# Find quantile or look up range for a new data point

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing this without using nested `ifelse()` statements, which I know slows R down dramatically. I can't share my actual data (which uses twentiles, not pentiles), but hopefully I can illustrate the problem below.

Assume I have the following dataframe of pentiles and maximum values.

```
pentiles <- data.frame(pentile = c(1:5), max_value = c(seq(10,50,10)))
```

For a new dataframe, I want to be able to look up which pentile a given value is in, and then return that pentile. For example:

```
values <- data.frame(score = c(3, 15, 49, 34, 21))
```

should give a solution of `(1, 2, 5, 4, 3)` in some format (stand-alone vector or column in the `values` dataframe.

I'm quite familiar with `dplyr` and can't think of anything, but I appreciate there may be a `data.table` solution that I'm not aware of. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `?ntile` from dplyr?

Comment: I believe this will create new quantiles based on the data in `values`. I'm trying to track population shift over time, so the new values need to be grouped by the old/existing boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is a minimum value (e.g. 0):

```
as.numeric(cut(values[,1], c(0, pentiles$max_value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `pentiles` data frame is sorted, you can do

```
tmp <- cbind(pentiles$max_value)[, rep(1, length(values$score))]
pentiles$pentile[apply(sweep(tmp, 2, values$score) >= 0, 2, which.max)]
```

It performs unnecessary operations but may still be faster than a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for this. This did work, but the other answer suggested is a little neater and ran quicker. I appreciate the effort.